# Ich bin mir bewusst vs mir ist bewusst

Tags: translation, english-to-german, meaning, usage, meaning-in-context

Beides wird als *I'm aware* ins Englische übersetzt. Gibt es dazwischen irgendeinen Unterschied in Bezug auf die Bedeutung? Oder ist es halt eine Sache der Ausdrucksweise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich hätte da spontan keinen großen Bedeutungsunterschied wahrgenommen, aber der [Duden-Eintrag für bewusst](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bewusst) unterscheidet im Abschnitt "Bedeutungen, Beispiele und Wendungen":

> **1. b. klar erkennend, geistig wach:**
>   ...
>   **Wendungen, Redensarten, Sprichwörter**
>   sich  einer Sache bewusst sein (sich über etwas im Klaren sein: sich der Bedeutung einer Sache voll bewusst sein)
>
> **1. c. ins klare, wache Bewusstsein gedrungen, im klaren, wachen Bewusstsein vorhanden**
>   ...
>   etwas ist jemandem bewusst (jemand weiß etwas)

Comment: Ich hätte erst mal in Duden nachschlagen sollen. Gibt es ja einen deutlichen Unterschied.